# Json validation oneof validation

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, ajv

So I had this json

```json
{
"f1":"John", 
"f2":"whatever",
"f3":"abc"
}
```

I wanted to validate it as only one of `f1`, `f2`, `f3` should be present. If neither `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are present then it should pass.

Something like,

```json
{
"f1":"John", 
}
```

PASS

```json
{
"f1":"John", 
"f2":"whatever",
}
```

FAIL

```json
{
"f1":"John", 
"f2":"whatever",
"f3":"abc"
}
```

FAIL

```json
{}
```

PASS

---

Here is the code I wrote but it is failing

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "required": [
          "f1"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "required": [
            "f2", "f3"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "required": [
          "f3"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "required": [
            "f2", "f1"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "required": [
          "f2"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "required": [
            "f3", "f1"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:
snippet of schema https://jsonschema.dev/s/eN6Db

Comment: ajv.js here's the snippet of schema
https://jsonschema.dev/s/eN6Db

Well I am just validating the json! How would be use of json be helpful with the question?

Comment: Do you HAVE to use jsonschema or is it just one of the tool? Because more usual way is to use some validation tool such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi . There you can write your own validators - sometimes its much easier to write small script than try to modify some schema to validate some very custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements as given, you don't need to check against the other properties as they are defined. A schema like this would be sufficient:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "properties": {
    "f1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "f2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "f3": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "minProperties": 0,
  "maxProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

However, this does not work if you also need other properties at this level.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.
You can add `else: false` to each of your subschemas ([demo](https://jsonschema.dev/s/hQmQh))
OR, remove the conditional checks and use `oneOf`. You'd have to also add a subschema to allow for empty objects. The second approach may be preferable.

Here's the schema and a [demo](https://jsonschema.dev/s/zeJjJ).

```json
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "f1"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "f2",
          "f3"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "f3"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "f2",
          "f1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "f2"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "f3",
          "f1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a concise little trick to express this kind of constraint using the `dependencies` (or `dependentSchemas` if >= 2019-09) keyword.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "f1": {},
    "f2": {},
    "f3": {}
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "f1": { "not": { "required": ["f2"] } },
    "f2": { "not": { "required": ["f3"] } },
    "f3": { "not": { "required": ["f1"] } }
  }
}
```